# Reading a .txt text file in C containing float, separated by space

Tags: c, text

it looks common and obvious but I've already read txt file in C in the past and here I am really stuck.

I have a txt file of this format

```
0.00000587898458 0.0014451541000 0.000000000001245
0.00012454712235 0.1245465756945 0.012454712115140
```

... with 640 columns and 480 lines.

I want to put each number of my txt file in a float with the maximum of precision as it is possible, and in a for loop.

```
FILE* myfile=NULL;
double myvariable=0.0;
myfile=fopen("myfile.txt","r");

for(i =0, k=0 ; i< height; i++)
    for (j=0 ; j< width ; j++){
fscanf(myfile,"%0.20f",&myvariable);
printf("%0.20f",myvariable);
k++;
}
}
fclose(myfile);
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It just keep reading nothing, it's full of zeros but with the right precision 0.00000000000. i tried to change my first number and it is still the same.

Comment: ignoring warnings is very bad practice

Comment: The code you've shown us does not compile.  Re-edit your question, and copy-and-paste the *exact* source code that you actually fed to your compiler.  It's hard to guess what's wrong with your program without seeing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several errors in your program - mismatched braces, undefined variables, etc.  The most important, however, and the one most likely to be causing your problem, is that you're not passing a pointer to `myvariable` in your `fscanf()` call.  You'll want to use `&myvariable` there, so that `fscanf()` can fill it in appropriately.  You probably don't need the format string to be so complicated, either - `"%lf"` should work just fine to read a `double`.  In fact, `gcc` warns me with your format string:

> ```
> example.c:16: warning: zero width in scanf format
> example.c:16: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format
> ```

And then my output becomes just 0.  Try `"%lf"`.  Here's a complete working example with your sample input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 2
#define WIDTH  3

int main(void)
{
  FILE *myfile;
  double myvariable;
  int i;
  int j;

  myfile=fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

  for(i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j < WIDTH; j++)
    {
      fscanf(myfile,"%lf",&myvariable);
      printf("%.15f ",myvariable);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  fclose(myfile);
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./example 
0.000005878984580 0.001445154100000 0.000000000001245 
0.000124547122350 0.124546575694500 0.012454712115140
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo for the &

Answer (score 3):

```
 fscanf(myfile,"%0.20f",myvariable);
```

You have to pass a pointer, use &myvariable instead.  Fix:

```
 fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &myvariable);
```

Comment: Yes sorry I made a mistake when I copy it here. But there was a & in my code

Comment: `%0.20f` is nonsense. `fscanf` does not use `printf`-style width/precision. Just use `%lf`.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, since you haven't shown us your actual source code, but ...

`fscanf`'s `"%f"` format expects a pointer to `float`; you're giving it a pointer to `double`.  That's probably what's causing the problem you're seeing.  Use `"%lf"` for `double` (or `"%Lf"` for `long double`).

Yes, this is an inconsistency between the `*printf` and `*scanf` functions.  It exists because `float` arguments to `*printf` are promoted to `double`; there's no such promotion for pointers, such as the `float*` arguments you might pass to `fscanf`.

And just use `"%lf"`, not `"%0.20lf"`; I'm not sure the latter is even valid.

Comment: useful to point the different data type of "float" and "double" in reading.

Answer (score 0):

1. You say you are stuck, but do not get into specifics regarding what exactly is the problem you are encountering.
2. You most likely intended to pass the address of 'myvariable' to fscanf.
3. Even if you don't care so much about precision (and in your case, you clearly say tjat you do), you should prefer double over float.  You should choose float only when you have a very strong reason for preferring float over double, and even that, should be in very specific situations.
4. Always check calls to fopen to ensure that it succeeded.

Comment: sorry it was a typo for the &