# load float/double matrix from txt using c++

Tags: c++, file-io, matrix, floating-point

It seems pretty dumb, but I am having a hard time loading a matrix type `double` I have on a txt file. inside  it has signed `double`s things like

```
11707.2 -919.303 -322.04 2260.71 2443.85 -4629.31 3082.64 -4209.86
-1741.71 298.192 -5658.34 2377.03 -3039 -2049.99 2788 -1915.9
```

and so on, and I have it in a txt file.

I have used `fscanf`, `ifstream` and all sorts of things I have found and am familiar with, but I have not been able to load it. I found on related question but the procedure didnt help me.

I need to save those values to a float array, but right now I just want to be able to load them correctly, all values look like the ones I wrote.

help please? any one?

Related question: [Reading a .txt text file in C containing float, separated by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151922/reading-a-txt-text-file-in-c-containing-float-separated-by-space)

Comment: The other question is *related* but is also concerning a *different programming language*. Can you share your `ifstream` implementation and we may be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard idiom:

```
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <sstream>   // for std::istringstream
#include <string>    // for std::string and std::getline

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        // process line, e.g. one matrix per line:

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<double> m;
        m.reserve(16);
        double d;

        if (iss >> d) { m.push_back(d); }
        else { /* error processing this line */ }

        if (m.size() != 16) { /* error */ }

        // use m
    }
}
```

If your matrix data is spread out over multiple lines, modify the code accordingly.